# "join" with (*) as parameter to create square function ?

Tags: haskell

I was playing a bit with [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io) and when I entered "\x -> x*x" (aka square function), it did output this

```
join (*)
```

I didn't know this, and I checked it on Hoogle:

```
-- | The 'join' function is the conventional monad join operator. It
-- is used to remove one level of monadic structure, projecting its
-- bound argument into the outer level.
join              :: (Monad m) => m (m a) -> m a
join x            =  x >>= id
```

I have no idea about how this works to create a function that returns the square of its param. Any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `((->)r)` type forms a monad with the following instance [definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-645)

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where
  f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
```

And `join` has the following [definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#join)

```
join x =  x >>= id
```

So let's start filling stuff in.

```
join (*)
= (*) >>= id
= \r -> id ((*) r) r
= \r -> r * r
```